# Share config between two grails apps that share a common plugin

Tags: grails, config, grails-plugin

We will have two apps that both need to use the same services/utilities/code/configuration.

We are using grailsApplication.config.* to configure things like URLs to external services. These are different depending on whether the app is running in dev/test/qa/staging/prod, so we have used the environments section in Config.groovy. We'll need the same URLs/environments configured for both applications.

In order to avoid duplication, we are trying to build a plugin that will hold all the shared stuff. This works for services and such, but Grails plugins do not include Config.groovy, resources.groovy so all the URL configuration and such can't be put in Config.groovy in the plugin.

Is there a nice way to put that configuration in a single place and have it available for both apps?

Perhaps we could put it in some place in the plugin and "import" it into the Config.groovy of both apps?

Comment: Do you want the configuration to live in the plugins? Sorry, trying to understand the setup here.

Comment: I've rewritten the question to be more clear. Configuration in the plugin would be nice so we could avoid duplicating it in both apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grails.config.locations` definition for external configuration files can include `java.lang.Class` objects to load configuration from pre-compiled Groovy scripts, as well as `file:` or `classpath:` URLs to parse Groovy or `.properties` files at runtime.  So you should be able to create a configuration file in the plugin under `src/groovy`

**{plugin}/src/groovy/com/example/CommonConfiguration.groovy**

```
package com.example

environments {
  production {
    ...
  }
  development {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then in the applications' `Config.groovy` files include this class in `grails.config.locations`

```
grails.config.locations = [com.example.CommonConfiguration]
```

However this does mean that when the plugin's `CommonConfiguration` and the host app's `Config.groovy` both specify a value for the same property, the *plugin* would win.  To redress the balance, you'd need to put a second external in `grails.config.locations` (which could be another `Class` or a URL)

```
grails.config.locations = [com.example.CommonConfiguration,
                           "file:app-config.groovy"]
```

and put app configuration in there (as later externals override earlier ones).

Comment: note, that grails.config.locations must be the last line in config.groovy so the external config can override everything

Comment: @johnSmith no, it can go anywhere. The whole of `Config.groovy` is parsed first, then the value of `grails.config.locations` is extracted from the parsed config, then each external is parsed in turn and merged into the main one.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to embed the configuration within the plugin you will need to make your plugin smart enough to read it's own configuration and merge that into the containing applications config. The following is based on Grails 1.3.7. The configuration holder may have changed since then (2.0 did a lot of house cleaning) but I am sure you can figure that part out. This example assumes that there is a configuration file called grails-app/conf/MyPluginConfig.groovy inside your plugin.

Inside your /MyPlugin.groovy you will add this merge of your configuration in the doWithSpring  closure.

```
def doWithSpring = {
    // get the current application configuration
    def currentConfig = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config
    GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().classLoader)

    // get the plugin configuration
    def pluginConfig = new ConfigSlurper(grails.util.GrailsUtil.environment).parse(classLoader.loadClass('MyPluginConfig'))

    // merge the configurations
    pluginConfig.merge(currentConfig)

    // set the application configuration to the merged configuration
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config = pluginConfig
}
```

That's it in a nutshell. Hope this helps.

Also, take note that you can still override the values in your containing application because of the way the merge is done. The application configuration is merged into the plugin configuration. If the containing application defines something it will override the plugins value.

Comment: Agreed. Our grails app is mainly composed of plugins. Each has its own defaults (even the one that is shared between two applications). Merging the default configs and a config that *may* be put in place by clients lets us doc our defaults and the appropriate tags for clients to override the defaults. Works great.

Comment: This in combination with external configuration files for the app itself makes for a winning combination in my experience.