# Share a resources.groovy across grails applications

Tags: grails, config, grails-plugin

Similar to this question: [Share config between two grails apps that share a common plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342598/share-config-between-two-grails-apps-that-share-a-common-plugin/21344776)

But regarding resources.groovy instead of Config.groovy.

Is there some way to have a resources.groovy in a plugin that is then depended on from multiple apps so they have those resources available and autowired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of a convenient way to do this, but since the purpose of `resources.groovy` is to configure Spring beans you could create a plugin and configure the beans from the plugin's `doWithSpring` closure in its plugin descriptor. This would additionally benefit from versioning, dependency management, etc.

Comment: This appears to work great. And it appears that you can cut and paste the text directly from resources.groovy into the doWithSpring block.

Comment: Yep, it's the same BeanBuilder DSL

Comment: Yep, for me this is one of the purposes of the plugin descriptor.