# Grails: Using "external configuration" to get a plugin's data source

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration, datasource, external

I'm building a plugin that will contain sharable code and configuration for several applications.  One things that I'm trying to share is the data source information.  Basically I need the application to not have to define it's own data source and instead use the plugin's data source.  The best way that I can think of doing this is to take advantage of the external configuration functionality that's available in Grails (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration).  However, I'm not exactly sure how to do this.  All the examples I can find online show you how to do this when using an external file on the file system somewhere.  I want to use configuration files from the plugin.

According to the documentation linked to above you can specify a "config script" class to use like this:

```
grails.config.locations = [com.my.app.MyConfig]
```

This would probably work, however, I can't find documentation on what a "config script" class actually is and how to create one.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342598/share-config-between-two-grails-apps-that-share-a-common-plugin/21344402#21344402

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That helped a lot.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I would have copied the answer here but that didn't seem right ;)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `DataSource` file of your plugin will not be used (it's ignored in the package stage) but you can create another file that ends with "DataSource" (eg MyPluginDataSource). This is also true for `BootStrap` and `Config`.

You will probably need to leave the application DataSource file empty.